# 2 non-linearly correlated variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, sas

I am currently looking at some code that uses 2 independent variables, which look as follows when scatter plotted:

[image]

Clearly, they are (non) linearly correlated. IMHO this violates a key assumption of a linear model (the code currently uses PROC GLMSELECT to fit the model). is there anything I could do to rectify this? Any feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with the natural log, $ln(\dotso)$, like so (in R):

```
# Generate some data that fits the picture:
x <- seq(from = -6, to = -0.01, by = 0.01)
y <- 0.03/x
plot(x,y)
```

And you get this:
[image]

You can add some more noise to the picture, if you prefer, but it doesnt really matter. Now, if we assume there are no numbers in either $y$ or $x$ which are $=0$. We can simply take logs of the absolute numbers:

```
# Now make all the numbers positive, and take ln(...):
plot(log(x*-1), log(y*-1))
```

[image]

Which is linear (sorta)... It will not be this pretty for your data, but the idea is the same.

Comment: sorry not sure how this helps in my situation where I want to avoid linear correlation like this.

Comment: I am confused by your statement, in OP you say that the variables are non linearly related, and ask what you can do to rectify this. This is what I try to answer, can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. First of all I would like to know, if you agree with me that the variables are correlated and thus violate one of the key assumptions of linear regression. if this is true I would like to hear about possible solutions.

Comment: Btw one suggestion I had was to ignore everything less than -1 for both variables. If you look at the above scatter, this corresponds to zooming in and it looks much less correlated when you 'zoom' in.

Comment: I don't understand, correlation of variables is not a problem for the linear model... It's the entire idea? Are you talking about two independent variables? Those can be correlated aswell they just can't be perfectly correlated (which yours definitely aren't)

Comment: Yes I am talking about 2 independent variables - sorry maybe that's the cause of this confusion. So you in your opinion, looking at the scatter plot, this non linear correlation is not be a problem for use in a linear reg model?

Comment: No not at all, you can calculate the correlation and check that it isn't 1 or -1.